# Dynamic memory allocation without brackets

Tags: c++

I need to rewrite this code without using brackets.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct struct_set
{
    unsigned long long number;
    struct_set *next;
};

int main()
{
    struct_set s1[100];
    int a,n=1;
    cin >> a;
    s1[0].number = a;
    s1[0].next = NULL;
    cin >> a;
    while(a!=0)
    {
        s1[n].number = a;
        s1[n-1].next = &(s1[n]);
        cin >> a;
        ++n;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cout << s1[i].number << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I set size of the array `s1` to but I don't know this number. In exercise is written: totally random amount which value of number is no more than 2 to the power of 31. I can use `iostream`, `cstdio` and `stdio.h` libraries. No templates.

Does anyone have idea how to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to ask a *specific* question. Telling us what you need to do is not a question. What problem are you have trying to do what? Do do you not understand? Do you understand how to use pointers? Do you understand how to allocate? What *specifically* is giving you trouble?

Comment: This looks like a Homework problem. Tell us what you have already attempted and where precisely you're stuck. Don't expect the community to do your homework.

Comment: Surely, a homework question would not not stipulate 'no brackets'?  It sure does make using C++ imp.. 'very difficult'.  'int main()' is out, for a start :)

Comment: I mean [] brackets. How can I write for example struct_set s1 = new struct_set[100] without [] brackets?

Comment: @user3145385 `struct_set *s1 = (struct_set *) malloc (100 * sizeof(struct_set));`

Comment: I can't use malloc because there are only 3 allowed libraries: iostream, cstdio, stdio.h...

Comment: Make another struct with sufficient block-copied and renamed doubles to make enough space to store all your struct_sets.  Declare one and use it as workspace, accessing it via 'struct_set *' pointers.

Comment: So you can't use `malloc()` for dynamic allocation because the assignment forbids it, but you can use `new` for dynamic allocation since you're using C++. No header is required to use `new` (except in some advanced use cases).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
struct struct_set
{
    unsigned long long number;
    struct_set *next;
};
```

Is **linked list**

So there is not any need to write it as contiguous memory.

for more [Linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list)

*As it is homework, do that by yourself*

Answer (score 40):

I've been persuaded (blame Lounge<C++>) to post an answer that does (at least sort of) answer the question that was asked (how to write the code without brackets), even though it clearly misses the real point.

```
??=include <map>
??=include <string>
??=include <algorithm>
??=include <iostream>
??=include <iterator>
??=include <limits.h>

class xlat ??<
    std::map<char, std::string> table;
public:
    xlat() ??<
        for (int i = 0; i < UCHAR_MAX; i++)
            table??(i??) = i;
        table??('??='??) = "??" "=";
        table??('??/??/'??) = "??" "/";
        table??('??''??) = "??" "'";
        table??('??('??) = "??" "(";
        table??('??)'??) = "??" ")";
        table??('??!'??) = "??" "!";
        table??('??<'??) = "??" "<";
        table??('??>'??) = "??" ">";
        table??('??-'??) = "??" "-";
    ??>
    std::string operator()(unsigned char in) ??< return table??(in??); ??>
??>;

int main() ??<
    std::cin >> std::noskipws;
    std::transform(std::istream_iterator<char>(std::cin),
        std::istream_iterator<char>(),
        std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout),
        xlat());
??>
```

With this, you can write your code normally (using brackets where you see fit) then run it through this program (which works as a filter) to transform all brackets to their trigraph form, so the source code won't include any brackets (or braces). The ugliness you see above is the result of its having been run on its own source code, thus eliminating all brackets and braces.

For anybody who's into language-lawyer tricks, note how I've specified the strings containing the trigraph sequences. To maintain them as strings of three characters, each is written as a pair of adjacent string literals. Trigraph sequences are substituted in phase 1 of translation, but adjacent string literals aren't concatenated until phase 6, so the trigraph sequences aren't produced until after trigraph substitution has taken place.

Note on compiling: Both VC++ and g++ disable trigraph substitution by default. To compile this with those, you need to specify `--trigraph` with g++, and `/Zc:trigraph` with VC++.

As to the question originally asked: you normally build a linked list by allocating nodes in the linked list individually. Since you've specified C++ and your restrictions don't seem to elimninate the use of `new`, that's what you probably want to use. For example, let's build a linked list of some numbers, then print out the contents of the linked list:

```
struct node {
    unsigned long long number;
    node *next;
    node(unsigned long long n, node *next=nullptr) : number(n), next(next) {}
};

void destroy(node *root) {
    if (root==nullptr)
        return;
    destroy(root->next);
    delete root;
}

int main() {
    node *root = nullptr;

    // build the linked list:
    for (int i=0; i<20; i++)
        root = new node(i, root);        

    // print it out:
    for (node *temp = root; temp; temp = temp->next)
        std::cout << temp -> number << "\n";

    // destroy it:
    destroy(root);
}
```

Notes:

1. This source code lacks brackets (even without using the preceding monstrosity).
2. This uses a "raw" `new` to allocate each node. For production code you really don't want that, but the "right" approaches would require either writing all the code for a smart pointer on your own, or else violating the restrictions on what headers can be used. At a guess, it would probably also violate your professor's expectations.

Comment: +1 for gross indecency.

Comment: You could get rid of brackets in `node` definition by allocating a fixed number of bytes (instead of a struct) and using byte offsets instead of member access. Should be perfectly valid to do so. Oh also `malloc` not allowed is not a problem since `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1, so `new[] char` should do the trick.

Comment: Reversal badge. :D

Comment: +1 for lulz. Seriously, who in the clear mind would ask how to write c++ code without brackets?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a pointer to your structure then allocate memory for `100` element:

```
struct struct_set *s1;
s1 = (struct_set *)malloc(100*sizeof(struct_set));
```

You don't need to write `&(s1[n])` to get the adress of `s1[n]`. According to pointers arithmitics `s1+n` is the adress of `s1[n]`

```
    s1[n].number = a;
    s1[n-1].next = (s1+n);
```

Comment: As above, I can't use malloc because there are only 3 allowed libraries: iostream, cstdio, stdio.h...

Comment: Why only 3 are allowed?

Comment: use `::operator new()` instead of malloc?